# Что за ошибка MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:

Tags: android, java

Приложение отправляет запрос на сервер и получает строку JSon.

Все работает на версии андроид 2.3.7 и 4.0.2, 
а на версии 4.2.2 вылетает следующая ошибка:

**java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:**

```
   try {
        URL url = new URL(url_zapr);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(100000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(100000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // 200 OK
            inputstream = connection.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = inputstream.read()) != -1) { bos.write(read); }
            byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
            bos.close();
            data = new String(result);
        } else {data = connection.getResponseMessage() + " . Error Code : " + responseCode;}
        connection.disconnect();
        return data;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace();         Log.d(LOG_TAG,"e1= "+ e.toString());
    }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); Log.d(LOG_TAG,"e2"+ e.toString());}
    finally { if (inputstream != null) { Log.d(LOG_TAG,"e3"); inputstream.close(); }}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: работа с сетью в UI??

Comment: http://xxx.ru/mapi/login.php?email=xxx@nm.ru&sign=fwd510f5177cba400c920fa145a2c63c

Comment: проблема была в отсутствии WWW. Подставил и все заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Гугоо-о-ол! Ауу ты где?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21507718/2604639)

Ваш URI - не URI (c).

> Add http:// before the www... or https://.
>
> public String URL =
>   "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";

[image]

Comment: добавил еще www в строку и все заработало.
Благодарю!